# TensorFlow GradientDescentOptimizer not convering on expected cost

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm reviewing the material I did in Andrew Ng's class on ML and trying to implement it in TensorFlow. I was able to use scipy's `optimize` function to get a cost of 0.213, but with TensorFlow, it's stuck at `0.622`, not very far from the initial loss of `0.693` using an initial set of weights of zero.

I reviewed the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598365/why-does-my-gradientdescentoptimizer-produce-nan) and added a `tf.maximum` call to my loss function to prevent NaN's. I'm not convinced this is the right approach and I'm sure there is a better way. I also tried using `tf.clip_by_value` instead but that gives the same non-optimized cost.

```
iterations = 1500

with tf.Session() as sess:
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    theta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3,1]), dtype=tf.float32)
    training_rows = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    z = tf.matmul(X, theta)
    h_x = 1.0 / (1.0 + tf.exp(-z)) 
    lhs = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(-y), tf.log(tf.maximum(1e-5, h_x)))
    rhs = tf.matmul(tf.transpose((1 - y)), tf.log(tf.maximum(1e-5, 1 - h_x)))
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(lhs - rhs) / training_rows
    alpha = 0.001
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(alpha)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    # Run the session
    X_val, y_val = get_data()
    rows = X_val.shape[0]
    kwargs = {X: X_val, y: y_val, training_rows: rows}
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.assign(theta, np.array([0,0,0]).reshape(3,1)))
    print("Original cost before optimization is: {}".format(sess.run(loss, kwargs)))
    print("Optimizing loss function")
    costs = []
    for i in range(iterations):
        optimal_theta, result = sess.run([theta, train], {X: X_val, y: y_val, training_rows: rows})
        cost = sess.run(loss, kwargs)
        costs.append(cost)
    optimal_theta,loss = sess.run([theta, loss], {X: X_val, y: y_val, training_rows: rows})
    print("Optimal value for theta is: {} with a loss of: {}".format(optimal_theta, loss))
    plt.plot(costs)
    plt.show()
```

I also noticed that any learning rate greater than `0.001` would cause the optimizer to dance wildly back and forth with the loss. Is that normal? Finally, when I tried increasing the iterations to 25,000 I realized the cost when down to `0.53`. I was expecting that it would converge in much fewer iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Learned alot trying to figure this out. So far starters, I didn't realize that this part of the loss function could potentially be problematic:

```
loss = -y log(h(x)) + (1 - y) (log(1 - h(x)))
```

If h(x), which is the sigmoid function turns out to be 1 (and it can happen if z, i.e. X * theta comes out to be large) then we will be evaluating log(1 - 1) = log(0), and that's infinite.

To fix this problem, I had to use Feature Scaling to normalize the values I had for X. This ensures that X * theta was smaller and similarly z, the sigmoid function would not come out to 1. As z gets large e^-z tends towards zero. So, using feature scaling ensures that our values in z are relatively small and e^-z will have an actual value that can be added to 1 in the denominator calculation of:

```
z = 1 / (1 + e^-(X*theta))
```

And for reference, Feature Scaling just means subtracting the mean and dividing by the range.

```
(arr - mean) / (max - min)
```